# MobX Store variable assignment

Tags: javascript, mobx

What is the right way to assign value to MobX store variables?

I understand that setting array should be done with the replace() function otherwise regular array will be assigned to the variable and not observable array.

But what about objects? is the right way is to use setObject1() or setObject2()? I tried both options and both works

What about primitive types and variable initiate with null? again regular assignment works but is it the right way?

```
class store {
  @observable array = [];
  @observable object = {};
  @observable primitive = 1;
  @observable nullObj = null

  @action setArray = array => {
    this.array.replace(array)
  }

  @action setObject1 = object => {
    this.object = object
  } 

  @action setObject2 = object => {
    this.object = observable(object)
  } 

  @action setPrimitive = primitive => {
    this.primitive = primitive
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use [**extendObservable**](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/extend-observable.html) so that you don't lose the reference to the original observable object.

**Example**

```
class Store {
  @observable array = [];
  @observable object = {};
  @observable primitive = 1;
  @observable nullObj = null

  @action setObject = object => {
    extendObservable(this.object, object);
  } 
}
```

If there are new properties in the new object, those properties will not be observable. You might want to use an [**observable map**](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/map.html) instead, if that is the case. This is brought up in the [**Common pitfalls & best practices**](https://mobx.js.org/best/pitfalls.html) section of the documentation:

> MobX observable objects do not detect or react to property assignments
>   that weren't declared observable before. So MobX observable objects
>   act as records with predefined keys. You can use
>   `extendObservable(target, props)` to introduce new observable
>   properties to an object. However object iterators like `for .. in` or
>   `Object.keys()` won't react to this automatically. If you need a
>   dynamically keyed object, for example to store users by id, create
>   observable _map_s using
>   [**observable.map**](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/map.html).

Comment: I want to work with immutable objects and lose the original observable object, should I use this.object = observable(object) or this.object = object?

Comment: @Shahaf I see. MobX is mutable in nature, so if you replace the reference altogether, all your observers that observe the object will not work anymore.